# Передать title страницы в input JS

Tags: javascript, html

Необходимо передать заголовок странице в скрытое поле формы (Битрикс), в value. URL передаю так:

```
<span class="hidden_title"><?=$FORM->ShowInput('hidden_title')?></span>
<script>
  <!--получаем адрес страницы-->
  var url = window.location.href;
  <!--находим нужный элемент-->
  var el = document.querySelector("span.hidden_title input");
  <!--меняем значение value на адрес-->
  el.setAttribute("value", url);
</script>
```

Как подобным образом передать title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно на js получить title странице и вставить в нужный вам input

```js
console.log(document.title)
```

```html
<title>Title test</title>
```

Comment: я правильно понял, заменить window.location.href на console.log(document.title)? если да, то не работает, в результате пишет undefined

Comment: el.setAttribute("value", document.title); Попробуйте вот так, без console.log

Comment: так работает, спасибо!